# Prestashop adding category image

Tags: php, prestashop

I need to auto add a category image, when the category is created, this is what i do:

```
/* Get ext */
$size = getimagesize($this->url . str_replace(" ", "%20", $ImagePath));
$extension = image_type_to_extension($size[2]);

/* Get img */
$n_image = file_get_contents($this->url . str_replace(" ", "%20", $ImagePath));

/* Get name */
$parts = explode("/", $ImagePath);

file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . __PS_BASE_URI__ . "img/c/" . $categoryID . $extension, $n_image);

$img = new ImageCore();
$img->id_product = $cat->id;
$img->cover = true;
$img->position = 1;
$img->image_format = str_replace(".", null, $extension);
$img->legend = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
$img->add();
```

How would i add the data? And how do i associate it with the category?I have the ID $cat->id;

Is there a method, where i can provide the image data, or the path to the image, where it will auto create the dimensions required and associate it with the specific catagory->id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the postImage method of the adminController class. The, look at how is's implemented in adminCategoriesController.
I'd follow the same path instead of creating a new on that way.

Where are you doing that? If it's from a back office controller, you can access those methods yourself pretty easily, otherwise you have to clone them (they're protected)